# An 8 GB microSD card showing as 1.3 TB in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

My 8 GB [microSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Physical_size) card is showing as 1.3 TB in Windows 7, and I am unable to format it. How can I do it?

Note: it's been formatted with [ExFAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT).

Comment: maybe its a production glitch and you've got the worlds first 1.3TB micro SD card!!

Answer (score 2):

First off, SD cards bigger than 4 GB are not *normal* SD cards - they are the "new" standard called [SDHC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#SDHC), which means it's possible your card reader doesn't support it. Check it out first, or as *ultrasawblade* suggested, try putting it in a phone and connecting that via USB.

Otherwise, in Windows 7 you could try using `Disk Management` tool to delete/re-create the partition and re-format:

1. Right-click on the **Computer** icon on your desktop and select **Manage** (or alternately via the Start Menu > Computer > right-click):
   [image]
2. Now, click below on **Disk Management**:
   [image]
3. Find your drive, right-click and select **Delete Volume**.
4. Right-click again on your drive and select **Create Volume**
5. Right-click yet again on your drive and select **Format**
6. Enjoy your newly formatted drive(?)

Comment: hi glenneroo tried that but no option to delete volume

Comment: Did you check if your card reader supports SDHC cards? Another thing to check would be if the card is write-protected: there's a small switch on the side which you can move up or down to enable/disable write-protection. Unplug it from your reader, turn the switch off, plug it back in and open up disk management tool again.

Comment: its a micro sd card and no write protction on it

Answer (score 0):

Might be an issue with the controller reading the card.  Try:

- checking Windows Update to see if there are updated drivers for your SD reader drivers
- using a different device to read the card (try your phone if it has an SD card slot)